# Deferring a Dojo Deferred

Tags: dojo, widget, deferred

I'm having a bit of a problem getting a deferred returned from a method in a widget. The method is itself returns a Deferred as it's an xhrPost. The code is as such (using dojo 1.8)

Calling Code:

```
quorum = registry.byId("quorumPanel");

var deferredResponse = quorum.updateSelectionCount();

deferredResponse.then(function(data){
    console.log("Success: ", data);
}, function(err){
    console.log("Error: ", err);
});
```

and the code in the widget:

```
updateSelectionCount: function() {

    var self = this;

    var deferredResponse = xhr.post({
        url: "ajxclwrp.php",
        content: [arguments here],
        handleAs: "json"});

    deferredResponse.then(function(response) {

    var anotherDeferred = new Deferred();

        var _boolA = true;
        var _boolB = true;
        dojo.forEach(response.result, function(relationshipInfo){
            [do a bunch of stuff here too set _boolA and/or _boolB]
        });

        self._sethasRequiredAttr(_hasRequired);
        self._setHasRequestedAttr(_hasRequested);
        self.quorumInfo.innerHTML = quorumHtml;

        // Below is not working 
        anotherDeferred.resolve('foo');
        return anotherDeferred;

    });

}
```

Do I need to set up another promise and use promise/all. Im confused/frustrated at this point.

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

the .then() method returns another deferred. You just need to put a return statement in.

```
updateSelectionCount: function() {

    var self = this;

    var deferredResponse = xhr.post({
        url: "ajxclwrp.php",
        content: [arguments here],
        handleAs: "json"});

    return deferredResponse.then(function(response) {

        var _boolA = true;
        var _boolB = true;
        dojo.forEach(response.result, function(relationshipInfo){
            [do a bunch of stuff here too set _boolA and/or _boolB]
        });

        self._sethasRequiredAttr(_hasRequired);
        self._setHasRequestedAttr(_hasRequested);
        self.quorumInfo.innerHTML = quorumHtml;

        return "foo";
    });

}
```